# Setup Azure DevOps Notifications for commits/changes to specific branch

Tags: git, azure-devops, notifications

I want to be notified by email each time new commits are made to the master branch on our project.

Found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/manage-your-personal-notifications?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page) and know to do what it says under the 'Add a custom subscription' heading...

However the example given is different to what i want, so I'm not sure what to put into the mandatory **'filter criteria'** section to **get an email each time a commit is pushed, by anyone, to a specific branch**...could go by trial and error with the options that sound plausible but wondering, **has anyone done this / what's the best way to do it?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to be notified by email each time new commits are made to the master branch on our project.

As is shown in your screenshot, `A commit is pushed` subscription could meet your requirements.

In **filter criteria**, you could try to add the filter `Branches updated contains master`

For example:

[image]

In this case, when a commit is pushed to the master branch(Affect all repos), it will send notification emails.

Comment: does not work for me, I'm using an ancient AZDO version from 2019, maybe this is yet another feature that is supposedly already included in 2019 but only started working in later versions

Comment: The notification only works on repos I create after defining the notification on my AzDOS 2022 Upd 1 setup.